# Why are the base cases for my BST not running when searching for a target node?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I am solving a `Binary search tree` problem where we are given a `target node`, and want to return the node with value that's closest to this target in the BST.

Here is my code:

```
def findClosestValueInBst(tree, target):
    if target == tree.value: 
        return target
    if target<tree.value and not tree.left: 
        return tree.value 
    if not tree.right and target > tree.value: 
        return target 
    
    if target < tree.value: 
        findClosestValueInBst(tree.left, target)
    else: 
        findClosestValueInBst(tree.right, target)
```

It is retuning `'None'` for many of the test cases. But running through the code on paper, it should be working.

It is because the base cases are not running in the case of `if target<tree.value and not tree.left` and `if not tree.right and target > tree.value`...

But any idea why it is not executing? - as I can't seem to figure it out!

As an example:

[image]

For the following, I trace the tree down to node 13 with my code, then 13.left is None, so we should return tree.value, but this is not executing for some reason.

Comment: Looks like forgotten `return` when doing recursion.

Comment: Thanks VPfB, can I also ask what the Space complexity is?- The solution says it is O(log(n)), but I think it is O(h). Which is correct, or are they the same thing? I think it is O(h), because in the worst case we hold at most an equal number of recursion calls as the height of the tree?

Comment: I think both are correct. The height of a tree is logarithmically proportional to the number of elements <==> the number of elements is proportional to 2**height (i.e exponentially)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add return statement for recursive calls. With the following part, it should work as expected.

```
if target < tree.value: 
    return findClosestValueInBst(tree.left, target)
return findClosestValueInBst(tree.right, target)
```

Comment: Thanks Berkay, can I also ask what the Space complexity is?- The solution says it is O(log(n)), but I think it is O(h). Which is correct, or are they the same thing? I think it is O(h), because in the worst case we hold at most an equal number of recursion calls as the height of the tree?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Normally, if there's a chain/list case (unbalanced tree) the number of calls(=height) will be equal to the number of nodes (i.e. O(n)). I think that the solutions refers to average case (balanced tree) where the height ~ log(n).